# How to create a QTextEdit with space for a caption in the border?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtwidgets

How i could create a `QTextEdit` with a space for a **caption** like seen on gmail:

[image]

The result I got with the code below:

[image]

I figured a way to calculate where the top border should end (Before Email) and start again (after phone), but I not figured how to clear the border in the area where 'caption' is drawn.

Example:

---

```
// textedit.h
class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QLabel* caption;
    TextEdit(QWidget* parent = 0) : QTextEdit(parent)
    {
        caption = new QLabel(this);
        caption->setText("Email or phone");
        
        caption->setStyleSheet(R"(
                font: 14px;
                font-weight: 900;
                color: #3762ab;
                
                border-radius: 4px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 30);
                margin-left: 32px;
        )");
        
        caption->adjustSize();

        auto caption_rect = caption->contentsRect();

        int caption_x = caption_rect.x();
        int caption_width = caption_rect.x() + caption_rect.width();

        qDebug() << "Position where the left border should end:\n" 
            << caption_x << "\n";
        qDebug() << "Position where the border start after the caption:\n" 
            << caption_width << "\n";        
    }
};
```

---

```
#include "textedit.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new TextEdit(this);

    ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("#centralWidget { background-color: #121212; }");
    textEdit->setStyleSheet(R"(
        QTextEdit
        {
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 3px solid #3762ab; 
            background-color: transparent;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    )");

    textEdit->setGeometry(100, 50, 300, 70);
}
```

I think to achieve this I would need to draw the borders in the paintEvent, so i tried:

```cpp
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {

        QTextEdit::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(viewport());

        int borderWidth = 4;

        QPen pen;
        pen.setWidth(borderWidth);
        //pen.setBrush(radialGrad);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

        QPoint center = viewport()->rect().center();
        auto r = this->contentsRect();

        QPainterPath path;
        //path.lineTo(0, 0);
        //path.moveTo(r.width(), 4);
        //painter.setClipPath(path);
         


        // Top border
        pen.setColor(Qt::red);
        painter.setPen(pen);

        // Line before the caption
        painter.drawLine(QLine(0, 0, caption_x, borderWidth));
        // Line after the caption
        painter.drawLine(QLine(caption_width, 0, r.width(), borderWidth));

        

        // Left border
        pen.setColor(Qt::white);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawLine(QLine(0, 0, borderWidth, r.height()));



        // Bottom border
        pen.setColor(Qt::green);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawLine(QLine(0, r.height() - borderWidth, r.width(), r.height()));



        // Right border
        pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawLine(QLine(r.width() - borderWidth, 0, r.width(), r.height()));

    }
```

Result:

[image]

I use different colors just to figure if each border was being drawn correctly...

Btw, the borders looks weird, looks like they are being drawn with a different thickness, and i'm not sure how to draw the lines curved.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommand you to use QGroupBox and style sheets to adjust all you want.

Here is an example (In QtDesigner, I just put a QLineEdit in a QGroupBox and made the layout of the groupBox horizontal).

```
    ui->groupBox->layout()->setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2);
    ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget{"\
                                     "background-color:black;}");

    ui->groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{"\
                                "color:blue;"\
                                "background-color:black;"\
                                "border: 1px solid;"\
                                "border-color: blue;"\
                                "border-radius: 5px;"\
                                "margin-top: 20px;}"\
                                "QGroupBox::title{"\
                                "subcontrol-origin: margin;"\
                                "left: 20px;"\
                                "padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;}");

    ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{"\
                                "color:white;"\
                                "background-color:black;"\
                                "border: none;}");
```

Here is what I've got :

[image: QLineEdit with caption via QGroupBox]